# I can't seem to figure out how to make these windows efficiently

Tags: modeling, mesh

This is what I'm trying to replicate:

[image]

[image]

I made the shape of the station but I'm stuck with the oval windows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a cube, subdivide it (smooth), cut it in half, select its middle edge, bevel it, select the bottom half, drag it down.

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe more of a curiosity to keep in your back pocket just in case you need something a bit more parametric, but you can make a capsule from a *Curve > Circle* set up as below:

[image]

..and a half-capsule by deleting one of the circle's control-points, and toggling 'Cyclic' to break it open.

The direction of the curve matters; you may have to switch that.

Comment: I really need to start using more curves they are really useful, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a plane, here it is rotated 90 degrees on `x`, and scaled a bit
   on `z`.

[image]

2. Vertex bevel the entire plane with
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

[image]

3. Add a *solidify modifier* and adjust thickness as desired.

[image]

Gif of the process:

[image]

Afterward, from the look of your reference you could probably use an array modifier to handle the copies.

Comment: from the reference photo it looks more like a bubble than a flat oblong

Comment: The array modifier worked wonders!